# Does using /dev/urandom break bash loops? (Break as in the non programming term for a loop break)

Tags: bash

I have a little problem with my first ever bash script.

The purpose is to make a file appended with a number with size of x, then make another file with the same basename with the number incremented by one each time until MAXFILES is met...

```
filename.something.r0
filename.something.r1
filename.something.r2
filename.something.r3
filename.something.r4
filename.something.r5
filename.something.r6
filename.something.r7
```

Each file has the same header then is filled with randomness till it reaches a filesize of 500GB... then proceeds to go to the next iteration of the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
COUNT=0
MAXFILES=8
MAXSIZE=524288000
HEADER=$(cat header)

while [ $COUNT -lt $MAXFILES ]; do
{
        FILE="filename.something.r$COUNT"
        echo $HEADER > $FILE
        FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s $FILE)
        while [ $FILESIZE -lt $MAXSIZE ]; do
        {
            cat /dev/urandom >> $FILE
            FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s $FILE)
        }
        done
        ((++$COUNT))
        echo $COUNT
}
done
```

What happens: File continues past the MAXSIZE value and does not loop until keyboard interrupt.

I have no idea why it's not working and suspect it's down to /dev/urandom being run indefinately even though. I assume this is standard behavior.

Reason: I was bored

I'm aware there are "better" ways of doing this, but it's annoying not getting my way to work. Especially when I am using this as a project for my first ever bash script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suspect, it is this line that is causing you trouble:

```
 cat /dev/urandom >> $FILE
```

If you run just that alone from a shell prompt you'll see that it runs forever. It's because `/dev/urandom` is a special file with no end, as long as you read from it it will provide you with more data.

For your script to work you need to read a specific amount of data from the device file, typically this is done with `dd` like so:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=$NBYTES count=1 >> $FILE
```

where `$NBYTES` is the number of bytes you want to read at a time.